# Stream grouping by sum of determinate objects

Tags: dictionary, java-8, java-stream, treemap, collectors

I have a Request class like this :

```
public class Request 
{
String name,destName;
int nSeats;
//Example : requestOne,Paris,3
...
}
```

I want to group the request in a Map |Integer,List of String| where the keys are the sum of the request with the same destName and the values are the destinations' names.

Here is my code:

```
public TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> destinationsPerNSeats() {
return requests.
stream().
collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Request::getnSeats, TreeMap::new, 
Collectors.mapping(Request::getDestName, Collectors.toList()))).
}
```

Input :

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> map = mgr.destinationsPerNSeats();
print(map);
```

Output : {4=[Paris], 3=[London, Berlin, Berlin], 2=[Paris]}

Output expected : {6=[Berlin, Paris], 3=[London]}

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: What did you use as Input?

Comment: what is the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need two `Stream` pipelines. The first will group the destinations and sum the total number of seat for each destination name, and the second will group the destination names by the number of seats:

```
public TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> destinationsPerNSeats() {
    return
        requests.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Request::getDestName, 
                                               Collectors.summingInt(Request::getnSeats)))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                               TreeMap::new,
                                               Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Testing your code with the following input:

```
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<> ();
requests.add (new Request("John","Paris",4));
requests.add (new Request("Ben","London",3));
requests.add (new Request("Dan","Berlin",3));
requests.add (new Request("Sara","Berlin",3));
requests.add (new Request("Jenn","Paris",2));
```

produces the `Map`:

```
{3=[London], 6=[Berlin, Paris]}
```